# Creating new model with association but without specify id

Tags: sequelize.js

Can I create a user model with a City model already exists?

For example:

```
var User = this.sequelize.define('User', {name: String})
var City = this.sequelize.define('City', {name: String})

User.belongsTo(City);
```

Now assuming I already have a record in the DB, something like:

```
| Id | Name   |
|----|--------|
| 1  | York   |
| 2  | London |
```

and I wont to create new user that live at London.

What is the best approach?

I tried:

```
User.create({name: 'John', City: 'London'}, {include: [City]})
```

but an error has thrown saying: cityId doesn't have a default value.

I'm trying to avoid retrieving the cityId first.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The automatically defined `setXXX` functions are the best way to do this:

```
User.create({ user_field_1: 'foo', user_field_2: 'bar' })
.then(function(new_user) {
  new_user.setCity(someCityInstance);
});
```

If you don't have the instance but know the key of the City instance you want to associate then directly specifying it at creation may work:

```
User.create({ user_field_1: 'foo', user_field_2: 'bar', city_id: 'xyz' });
```